# Match lookup results in error - Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: pandas, match

I have the following:

```
df1['Combined'] = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', C', 'C']
df1['Quantity'] = [0, 60, 75, 149, 205, 500, 250, 300, 500, 40, 45, 75, 80]

df2['Combined'] = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
df2['Min Q'] = [0, 50, 100, 150, 100, 0, 300, 400, 5, 50, 100] 
df2['Max Q'] = [49, 99, 149, 199, 199, 299, 399, 499, 60, 100, 149]
```

I want to add a column to df1 that returns the range from df2. I attempted as follows:

To calculate df2['Range']:

```
df2['Range'] = df2['Min Q'].astype(float).astype(str) + ' - ' + df2['Max Q'].astype(float).astype(str)
```

To lookup df1['Range']:

```
def lookup_Range(Range):
    match = (df2['Min Q'].astype(float) <= df1['Quantity'].astype(float)) & (df2['Max Q'].astype(float) >= df1['Quantity'].astype(float)) & (df1['Combined'] == df2['Combined'])
    Range = df2['Range'][match]
    return Range.values[0]

df1['Quantity'].apply(lookup_Range)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The columns repeat themselves but I thought I'd get a unique match in each instance. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) first with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df2['Range'] = df2['Min Q'].astype(str) + ' - ' + df2['Max Q'].astype(str)

df = df1.merge(df2, on='Combined')
df = df[df['Quantity'].between(df['Min Q'], df['Max Q'])]
print (df)
   Combined  Quantity  Min Q  Max Q      Range
0         A         0      0     49     0 - 49
5         A        60     50     99    50 - 99
9         A        75     50     99    50 - 99
14        A       149    100    149  100 - 149
25        B       250      0    299    0 - 299
30        B       300    300    399  300 - 399
36        C        40      5     60     5 - 60
39        C        45      5     60     5 - 60
43        C        75     50    100   50 - 100
46        C        80     50    100   50 - 100
```

If want also filter only some columns:

```
df = df.loc[df['Quantity'].between(df['Min Q'], df['Max Q']), ['Combined','Quantity','Range']]
print (df)
   Combined  Quantity      Range
0         A         0     0 - 49
5         A        60    50 - 99
9         A        75    50 - 99
14        A       149  100 - 149
25        B       250    0 - 299
30        B       300  300 - 399
36        C        40     5 - 60
39        C        45     5 - 60
43        C        75   50 - 100
46        C        80   50 - 100
```

Comment: interesting, didnt think about between. Nice @jezrael. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need:

```
bins = df2['Max Q'].tolist()
#[49, 99, 149, 199, 199, 299, 399, 499]
df1['bins']=pd.Series(np.searchsorted(bins, df1['Quantity'].values)).map(df2['Range'].to_dict())
print(df1)

  Combined  Quantity     bins
0        A         0     0-49
1        A        60    50-99
2        A        75    50-99
3        A       149  100-149
4        A       205    0-299
5        B       500      NaN
6        B       250    0-299
7        B       300  300-399
8        B       500      NaN
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. What if I also need df1['Combined'] = df2'[Combined'] before applying the bins? In reality, the bins will overlap, they won't always be ascending. I added 'C' to the 'Combined' columns within my example to illustrate.

Comment: I don't think it works exactly. I edited the first range of 'C' to be 5-60 to make it more clear. If I have df1['Combined', 'Quantity'] = ['A', 5], I'd want to pull the range associated with 'A' so 0-49. But if I have ['C', 45], I want to pull the range 5-60. The range is dependent on df1['Combined'] = df2'[Combined'] to pull the correct range. How can I add that condition?

Comment: seems like bins overlap so groupby may be required, unable to figure it right now. Will post if I find something

Comment: exactly, I agree with groupby, I think custom function should be good here

Comment: @jezrael but i am not able to come up with anything good. :( may be you can post an answer. :) OP & me needs help. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a mistypo in calcultaing df2['Range']. 'Max Q' instead of 'MaxQ'. Secondly can you please clarify what is your end goal? I tried to comment here but I don't have enough reputation. I will try to help you though

Comment: Oops, fixed. The searchsorted solution is very close to what I want to do, but I also want to consider where df1['Combined'] = df2['Combined']. I'm not sure how to add that extra condition.

Comment: I see, did you get it resolved, it seems the code offered above worked out